# Mapping objects gives back " function map() { [native code] } " .. why

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, axios

So, I am kinda at a lost why I am getting this back, is it because I am bringing the information back as text? I figured regardless it should still be able to go into the p tag.

previous to having the "function map() { [native code] }" return on the websites html, I had [Object, Object] . . .  returning to the HTML

index.html :

```
    <body>
    <p id="results">${results.map}</p>
    <h1>demo</h1>
</body>
```

Index Route:

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 
  scraper().then(results => {
    console.log("results are ", results);
    res.render('index', {locals: { results }})
  });
});
```

And then here is the scraper:

```
debug = require ('../models/conn');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function searchJobs(i) {
   const url = await axios.get('actual url')
    // return fetch(`${url}${i}`)
        .then(response =>  response)
        
        .then(res => {
            const jobs = [];
            const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

            $('.result').each((index, element) => {
                const title = $(element).children('.title').text();
                const linkToJob = $(element).children('.title').children('a').attr('href')
                const body = $(element).children('.summary').text();
                jobs[index] = { title, linkToJob, body };
            });
            console.log(jobs);
            return jobs;
            // Prints tbe second child of results class results for that page in console.
            //    console.log($('.result').children().eq(1).text());
        });
        return url;
};
module.exports = searchJobs;
```

So I have all the information console.loging that I want I am just trying to get it to display on the front-end of the page..

Would love some more help, still new to programming.. only been programming for real for about 3 months now..

Comment: Use just `<p id="results">${results}</p>`

Comment: `results` is an array of objects and `map()` is an array method.

Comment: @TamasSzoke that just returns [object Object],[object Object] and then it continues.

Comment: @palaѕн oh... I see, so I now I need to work on converting the array of objects into just simply a array of properties?

Comment: What view engine are you using?

Comment: Yup, simple way to test this is to use this in UI `<p id="results">${results[0].title}</p>`

Comment: @TamasSzoke Express, and that worked, I got a title back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `map` method over the `results` object. 
If you iterate over it with the `map` method, you could do something like this...

```
<body>
  {results.map(result => { return <p>{result}</p> })}
</body>
```

This is going to basically create a `<p>` tag for every result in your `results` object

Comment: Says I'm missing, a ) after argument list, and I had tried something like this earlier, as something like this is what I used to return other data arrays in previous little projects.

Comment: What I have "  `${results.map(result => { return <p>${result}</p> })}` " Also back ticks in the code, but can't show them in a comment.

Comment: Fixed the problem above gonna mark this as an answer because now I am on to new problems :P